# Hyperparameter tuning using neuralnet method in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, r-caret

I'm using Wisconsin Breast Cancer Dataset for **classification** problem: diagnosis of malignant or benign tumors. The dataset has 33 features, all features are numerical besides diagnosis (factor).
I'm trying to build DNN model and tune hyperparameters of **neuralnet method in train function**, but when I ran the model I get an error : **"Error: wrong model type for classification"**.
What should I do in this case?

```
set.seed(1)
library(neuralnet)

grid <- expand.grid(layer1=c(1:20), layer2=c(1:20), layer3=c(1:20))
DNN <- train(diagnosis ~., data = train.df, method = "neuralnet", linear.output = FALSE,
         tuneGrid = grid, metric = "Kappa", trControl=train_control, 
         maxit = 500, allowParallel = TRUE )

pred <- predict(DNN, newdata = valid.df)
confusionMatrix(pred, valid.df$diagnosis)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `neuralnet` method used in caret, can only be used for regression modelling, not classification. You need to select a different model. You can check which models can be used for classification with caret [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html).

For neuralnets and classification you can use `mxnet` and `nnet` methods.